# Sharepoint OData query fails to compile with Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I am scratching up a class library for a bunch of Sharepoint Lists we constantly need to query against.

The problem is, the query runs just fine through all pages (around 15 at server side pagination by 1000 items) if it is as simple as

```
query = Tickets.Expand(o => o.Property1).Expand(o => o.Property2)
```

The response is converted into a list which then can be further queried/sorted/what the user needs.
However I need to write up some more methods with predefined filters(by date, by user etc.)

and here the compiler throws errors at me.

```
public IEnumerable<TicketsItem> GetTicketsByDate(DateTime? startDate)
    {
        ResultList = new List<TicketsItem>();
        query = oDataService.Tickets.Where(d => d.EMail == "1");

        token = null;
        // Query ausführen
        response = oDataService.Execute<TicketsItem>(query.RequestUri) as QueryOperationResponse<TicketsItem>;
        do
        {
            // wenn Paging aktiv, nächste Seite vorbereiten
            if (token != null)
            {
                response = oDataService.Execute<TicketsItem>(token) as QueryOperationResponse<TicketsItem>;
            }
            // Query-Ergebnisse hinzufügen
            ResultList.AddRange(response);

        } while ((token = response.GetContinuation()) != null);

        return ResultList;
    }
```

The where clause is just a senseless mockup. The important part is the following error:

> "System.Linq.IQueryable"
>   cannot be implictly be converted to
>   "System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery"
>   (free translation from German to English)

Why does a query without a where clause runs fine and why does it fail with one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me.

```
query = oDataService.Tickets.Where(d => d.Created == dateStarted) as DataServiceQuery<TicketsItem>
```

did the trick